# Can't get arguments on PushNamed (always return Null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to get arguments when I click on notification.

The structure is :

- Firebase Cloud Messaging sends a notification with route name and other values.

```
    await _notificationsPlugin.show(
            id,
            message.notification!.title,
            message.notification!.body,
            notificationDetails,
            payload: json.encode(message.data),
          );
```

- I add a PushNamed when select notification.

```
_notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        // ignore: avoid_types_on_closure_parameters
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      final args = json.decode(payload!);
      if (args.route != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, args.route,
            arguments: 'data');
      }
    });
```

- And with a onGenerateRoute a tried to get this arguments. I get the route name but nothing arguments... I tried with String, int, Object.. nothing changes. **Arguments is always Null**

```
class AppRouter {
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    print('${settings.arguments}'); // always Null

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
            create: (context) => getIt<HomeBloc>()
              ..add(GetInfos(data: settings.arguments)),
            child: HomePage(data: settings.arguments),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated my code, for passing settings in MaterialPageRoute and getting arguments with ModalRoute, but doesn't work.. it's always null...

```
class AppRouter {
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: (_) => Screen());
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dynamic args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    print(args); // always Null

    return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
      create: (context) => getIt<HomeBloc>()
        ..add(GetInfos(data: args)),
      child: HomePage(data: args),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onGenerateRoute`, pass received route settings when creating `MaterialPageRoute`:

```
settings: settings,
```

After this, in the widget you set as `child`, for example `HomePage`, you can access arguments passed with `pushNamed` like (you need the have context):

```
final dynamic args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

**EDIT**: Please find below a minimal, working example of passing arguments with `onGenerateRoute` to another screen, and extracting it there:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      switch (settings.name) {
        case '/':
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHome());
        case 'myscreen':
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const MyScreen(), settings: settings);
      }
    });
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MyHome'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Go to MyScreen with argument: "hello"'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'myscreen',
                    arguments: 'hello'))));
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments ?? 'no argument given';
    print(args);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyScreen'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text(args as String)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work... I update my question with this new code, and yes.. arguments return always null..., have you an other idea for my problem ?

Comment: So in `AppRouter` class, `onGenerateRoute` function: is `settings.name` "home" and `settings.arguments` is null? And `args.route` in `onSelectNotification` is also "home"?

Comment: Yes exactly, args.route and settings.name return "home" but settings.arguments is null

Comment: I don't really get, why it is not working. I will add a minimal, reproducible example to my answer, implementing what I wrote earlier, maybe it helps.